# Duplicate an Android project for eclipse in windows

Tags: android, eclipse, copy, project

I would like to make an small program in Windows to duplicate an android project to use it in eclipse. I know that there is an option in eclipse (New Project -> Android Project -> create project from existing source), but I would like to automate this step (doing it programmatically in Java). Is there any command, script, etc to do so? I have tried copying the project folder, renaming every reference in the new project´s files and importing the new project into eclipse using a ZIP, but it does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try working with [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) may also suit your requirement

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Additionally, if you are working on multiple machines, do yourself a favour, and use some sort of version control (SVN, Git, etc.) That would make it easy to commit/checkout files across machines.

Comment: I am not trying to implement an alternative to SVN. I just want to use a previous project to build a new one.